# Travis CI runs only one test

Tags: angularjs, directive, travis-ci, karma-runner

I am setting up my [ng-scroll](https://github.com/Hill30/NGScroller) directive with Travis ci.

I have a set of tests with 47 tests in it. When I run it locally by using karma start they all run successfully, but travis reports success after running only one of them. At list this is what I see in the travis log.

What am I missing?

Hmm... it looks like it does run them all - it is the report that shows that only one has been executed. I intentionally broke a test, after that the report has shown 47 executed (1 failed)  on a separte line, the line executed 1 out of 47 was still there.

strange...

Comment: Not sure as I haven't used Travis but perhaps it reports 1 per test suite?

Comment: I've got one Angular directive being build with Travis as well, and it reports every test correctly. Our setups are quite different but the main difference I could notice is that I'm using PhantomJS to run the tests, while you're using Firefox. Perhaps something related to them? You can check out my configuration [here](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput), if you want to. Hopefully it might help you somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using `progress` reporter (which does rewrite the terminal output) and the output is clobbered with log or something. Try using `--reporters dots` on Travis.